# How to authenticate user in custom login() function?

Tags: php, laravel

I've overrided `login()` method in `LoginController`.

**Here's my method:**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->get()->first();
    if(!$user) {
        Session::flash('user.login', 'Пользователь не найден.');  
        return redirect()->route('login');          
    }

    if($user->active === 0) {
        Session::flash('user.login', 'Пользователь деактивирован.');
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Auth::login($user, true);
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    } else {
        Session::flash('user.login', 'Неверный пароль.');
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }   
}
```

But when the authentication of user passes, I get `401` error which means `Unauthenticated`.

I set up a middleware of `auth` in my `UserController`'s constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

What can be the reason of the `Unauthenticated` error?

**Edited:**

**`routes/web.php` file:**

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator')->group(function() {
        Route::get('acl', 'AclController@index')->name('acl.index');
        Route::post('permissions', 'PermissionController@store')->name('permissions.store');
        Route::put('roles', 'RoleController@update')->name('roles.update');
        Route::post('roles', 'RoleController@store')->name('roles.store');

        Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
        Route::put('users/password', 'UserController@changePassword')->name('password.change');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check to make sure you have write permission to `session`

Answer (score 0):

```
Do something like this:

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first(); 
//without get() to get record

$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
         // Authentication passed...
        // Auth::login($user, true);
        Session::put( 'name', $request->get ( 'username' ) );
        Session::flash('user.login', 'Logged in');
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    } else {
        Session::flash('user.login', 'Неверный пароль.');
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
```